# Thumb stick position only once

Tags: c++, arduino

I am using the following code to determin where the thumb joystick is positioned:

```
const int Left = 1;
const int Right = 2;
const int Up = 3;
const int Down = 4;
const int Center = 0;
int lastButton = -1;

int xpin = 4;
int ypin = 5;

int xAxis;
int yAxis;
char* myStrings[]={"Left","Right","Up","Down"};
int button;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    xAxis=map(analogRead(xpin), 0, 1023, 0, 10);
    yAxis=map(analogRead(ypin), 0, 1023, 0, 10);

    if (button == lastButton) {
        //Serial.println(0);
        //button = 0;
        delay(50);
    } else {
        if (xAxis < 4 ) {
            button = Left;
        }
        else if (xAxis > 6 ) {
            button = Right;
        }

        if (yAxis < 4 ) {
            button = Down;
        }
        else if (yAxis > 6 ) {
            button = Up;
        }

        Serial.println(myStrings[button-1]);
        button = 0;
        delay(50);
    }

    lastButton = button;
}
```

The code above works just fine on my arduino but i am looking to only get the postion **ONCE** and not every second while its held there.

How can i change the code to only take just **one value until its centered (0)** again?

Example:

If i move the joystick to the left it reads:

```
Left
Left
Left
Left
etc etc until i release it.
```

What i am looking to do is this:

```
Left
then it stops until i release it.
```

Any help would be great!

**update**

```
 if (xAxis ==5 ) { 
   button = Center; 
 }

 if (yAxis ==5 ) { 
   button = Center; 
 }
```

Seems to work well with Up and Down but not really for Left and Right. Sometimes it works, more often it doesn't.

Comment: Have boolean variables like `isLeft` that you set when it's moved left or released. I'm not totally sure how well it works for a joystick, but it does pretty well for normal keys.

Comment: Where is `lastButton` initialized?

Comment: **int lastButton = -1;**

Comment: @StealthRT: The code in your else-clause is the one changing `button`, it should be moved before the if-clause. (That's why I put `// Read button state`before the `if` in my example)

Comment: `button = 0;` certainly doesn't seem useful...

Comment: @ildjarn: It is actually useful, but obviously not in that place. It is should be put in before the other possible assignments to button, to make sure button is always assigned.

Comment: @Kleist : `button` appears to be in namespace scope, so it is guaranteed to be zero-initialized at program startup. I was referring to setting it to `0` just before setting `lastButton = button;`.

Comment: @StealthRT I posted my own answer, did it work for you?

Comment: @ildjarn: I'm not talking about initialization, I'm talking about every time the loop is entered.

Comment: @StealthRT: Did you try my "complete cleaned up code"?

Comment: @Kleist: Can not use most of that code since i am using arduino to compile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember where you were at the last iteration and compare to that to see if it has changed:

```
int lastButton = 0;
...
void loop() {
    button = ...// Read button state
    ...
    if (button != lastButton) {
        ... // New keypress
        lastButton = button;
    }
}
```

Complete cleaned up code:

```
enum ButtonState { Neutral=0, Left=1, Right=2, Up=3, Down=4 };

ButtonState lastButton = Neutral;

const int XPin = 4;
const int YPin = 5;

char* myStrings[]={"Neutral", "Left","Right","Up","Down"};

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

ButtonState readButtonState() {
    int xAxis=map(analogRead(XPin), 0, 1023, 0, 10);
    int yAxis=map(analogRead(YPin), 0, 1023, 0, 10);
    if (xAxis < 4 ) return Left;
    if (xAxis > 6 ) return Right;
    if (yAxis < 4 ) return Down;
    if (yAxis > 6 ) return Up;
    return Neutral;
}

void loop() {
    ButtonState button = readButtonState();
    if (button != lastButton) {
        Serial.println(myStrings[button]);
        lastButton = button;
    }
    delay(50);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `lastButton = button;` go inside the conditional code?

Comment: It doesn't have to, but moving it inside would of course skip the assignment when it is not necessary.

Comment: @Kleist: I updated my OP with my modification but it doesn't display anything now...

Comment: @StealthRT Maybe try using `-1` as the initial value for `lastButton`.

Comment: @DesmondHume: Still has the same effect using **-1**

Comment: @DesmondHume: Why wouldn't 0 work? None of Left, Right, Up or Down has the value 0.

Comment: @Kleist But he is assigning `0` to `button` at a few points of his code, so it got some meaning (probably irrelevant) for him, so you can't say that the role of `0` is completely vacant.

Comment: @DesmondHume: I never said 0 was "vacant". I just claim that it will work when initializing lastButton to 0.

Comment: @Kleist Why would you initialize `lastButton` with `Neutral` when the program has no idea what the last position of the joystick was? The program can start with the user having the joystick in Left or Right position but it should still assume that the last position was `Neutral`? What `-1` means is "the last position is unknown". Doesn't it make more sense?

Comment: @DesmondHume: It makes more sense if "The joystick was in Neutral when you started your program" is an event you want to do something with. I assume you don't.

Answer (score 0):

It should be more like this:

```
const int Left = 1;
const int Right = 2;
const int Up = 3;
const int Down = 4;

int xpin = 4;
int ypin = 5;

int xAxis;
int yAxis;
char* myStrings[]={"Left","Right","Up","Down"};
int button;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
int lastButton = -1; // init lastButton to a never occurring value

void loop() {

   xAxis=map(analogRead(xpin), 0, 1023, 0, 10);
   yAxis=map(analogRead(ypin), 0, 1023, 0, 10);

   if (xAxis < 4 ) { 
     button = Left; 
   }
   else if (xAxis > 6 ) { 
     button = Right; 
   }

   if (yAxis < 4 ) { 
     button = Down; 
   }
   else if (yAxis > 6 ) { 
     button = Up;
   }

   if (button == lastButton){
       //Serial.println(0);
       //button = 0;
       delay(50); // wait more
   }else{
       lastButton = button;
       Serial.println(myStrings[button-1]);
       button = 0;
       delay(50);
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. It's working but if i wanted to do **Left** and then **center** then **Left** again it doesn't register until i go some other position then back to **Left**?

Comment: @StealthRT Then you should associate a value with new Center constant (`0` would do as `-1` is associated with "no position has yet detected"), appropriately detect the centered position of the joystick and assign the associated value to `button` before the `if (button == lastButton)` condition takes place.

Comment: @StealthRT I think you should go on your own from here. I'm not familiar with arduino and its codes for joystick positions, or whatever. Sorry. I helped as much as I could.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this google code project, the author really did some great work here.  I'm using this in a project of mine and it requires VERY little customization (if any at all).

This is a joystick widget that is already very solid and is easily customizable.  I'm always hesitant to use other people's code, but it would have taken me quite a while to make anything as awesome as this.

**Demo**: http://code.google.com/p/mobile-anarchy-widgets/wiki/JoystickView

**Source**: http://code.google.com/p/mobile-anarchy-widgets/source/browse/trunk/Widgets/src/com/MobileAnarchy/Android/Widgets/Joystick/JoystickView.java